# Can't find gstreamer plugins after installing them

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer

I am trying to use GStreamer in Ubuntu 16.04, and I need something like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=x.x.x.x port=5000 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink sync=false`

however when I type `gst-inspect-1.0 avdec_h264` or any of the plugins in the list, it results in `No such element or plugin`

I already tried installing libav, ugly, bad, good:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm5.0 linux-headers-4.13.0-41 linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-43
  linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-24 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-29
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-30 linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-4.15.0-32 linux-headers-4.15.0-32-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-33
  linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic linux-image-4.15.0-32-generic linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-24-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-41-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-signed-image-4.13.0-45-generic
  qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 54 not to upgrade.

I also looked in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0, and found nothing

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried deleting plugins cache (on my debian it's in `~/.gstreamer-0.10/registry.x86_64.bin`)?

Comment: Also, what does `gst-inspect-1.0` alone writes - is there any plugin you wanted to install? Maybe plugin just changed the name.. ?

Comment: Also, another possibility - it may be necessary to build the plugins with the h264 encoder/decoder yourself, because it could be disabled for copyright/royalities reasons (or something similar) in "distribution" package.

Comment: Grep for the element, the actual name might be a bit different from the one you are searching for. `gst-launch-1.0 |  grep *avdec_*`

Comment: I need to install gdpdepay, rtph264depay, avdec_h264, or anything that does the same job. I can't find any of them with gst-inspect-1.0

Comment: I also get no results with `gst-launch-1.0 | grep *avdec_*`

Comment: Are you using anaconda or its varieties (miniconda etc.)?

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler no

Answer (score 4):

If you have anaconda installed and you do which gst-launch-1.0, it will most likely point to anaconda location which only had gst-plugins-base. So directly launching the /usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 fixed the issues for me as it was able to find the bad, good etc plugins.

Comment: Works! Is there any way to make this permanently available?